# Can't install gem-wrappers gem in 1 gemsets on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm

I'm really new in programming, I've been trying to install to install Rvm and then Ruby but here is where I get stuck when I try to install RVM on my Mac OS X 10.9:

```
MacBook-Air-de-Lucas:~ lucaslebrun$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    624      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   625
100 20819  100 20819    0     0  22711      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
Downloading https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/archive/stable.tar.gz

Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/lucaslebrun/.profile /Users/lucaslebrun/.bashrc /Users/lucaslebrun/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/lucaslebrun/.bash_profile /Users/lucaslebrun/.zlogin.
    Installing rvm gem in 1 gemsets./scripts/functions/gemset: line 118: 18872 Trace/BPT trap: 5       "${rvm_ruby_binary}" -rrubygems -e "$gem_spec" 2> /dev/null
Error running 'command gem install /Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/gem-cache/rvm-1.11.3.9.gem --local --no-ri --no-rdoc',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/log/1412952496_ruby-2.1.3/gem.install.rvm.log
[2014-10-10 10:48:16] command
current path: /Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/src/rvm
GEM_HOME=/Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global
PATH=/Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/bin:/Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin:/Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
GEM_PATH=/Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global
command(7): command gem install /Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/gem-cache/rvm-1.11.3.9.gem --local --no-ri --no-rdoc
+ ./scripts/functions/utility_logging : __rvm_log_dotted()  210 > gem install /Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/gem-cache/rvm-1.11.3.9.gem --local --no-ri --no-rdoc
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
  Reason: image not found
./scripts/functions/utility_logging: line 210: 18897 Trace/BPT trap: 5       gem install /Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/gem-cache/rvm-1.11.3.9.gem --local --no-ri --no-rdoc
.
    Installing gem-wrappers gem in 1 gemsets./scripts/functions/gemset: line 118: 18934 Trace/BPT trap: 5       "${rvm_ruby_binary}" -rrubygems -e "$gem_spec" 2> /dev/null
Error running 'command gem install gem-wrappers -v >=1.2.4 --no-ri --no-rdoc',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/log/1412952497_ruby-2.1.3/gem.install.gem-wrappers->=1.2.4.log
[2014-10-10 10:48:17] command
current path: /Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/src/rvm
GEM_HOME=/Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global
PATH=/Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/bin:/Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin:/Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
GEM_PATH=/Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global
command(8): command gem install gem-wrappers -v >=1.2.4 --no-ri --no-rdoc
+ ./scripts/functions/utility_logging : __rvm_log_dotted()  210 > gem install gem-wrappers -v '>=1.2.4' --no-ri --no-rdoc
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
  Reason: image not found
./scripts/functions/utility_logging: line 210: 18958 Trace/BPT trap: 5       gem install gem-wrappers -v >=1.2.4 --no-ri --no-rdoc
.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/ is complete.
```

And then I try to install Ruby but here is what I get:

```
Last login: Fri Oct 10 10:51:02 on ttys000
MacBook-Air-de-Lucas:~ lucaslebrun$ type rvm | head -n 1
rvm is a function
MacBook-Air-de-Lucas:~ lucaslebrun$ rvm use ruby --install --default
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.3'.
Using /Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/lucaslebrun/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/ruby
  Reason: image not found
MacBook-Air-de-Lucas:~ lucaslebrun$ ruby -v
```

What can I do ?

Comment: The error is suggesting that you might try to run 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles'. Have you tried to do that?

Comment: I get the same error, tried the above... what gives? What does broken binary version mean? If I disable it... what are the consequences?

Answer (score 0):

this is broken binary version of ruby 2.1.3, you can fix it with:

```
rvm reinstall 2.1.3 --disable-binary
```

Comment: to speed up ruby installation RVM provides compiled rubies (binaries), one of the binaries is broken, unfortunately this binary is provided by travis and they need it, I will build new binary soon and it will have higher priority then the travis one

Comment: I don't even know what compiled rubies or binaries mean. I need to Google a lot of stuff...

Comment: when you write a program it has a source code, the code is not always understood by your system, to make it readable for system the source needs to be translated (compiled), the resulting translation is a binary - something your system can read but you cant

Comment: haha, this destroyed my environment. Did it my current version too. Now I have to deal with a series of new cryptic error messages. Fun times.